# Multiple jQuery scripts don't work at a same page

Tags: jquery

I'm a php developer, but sometimes I use jQuery (ready made codes). This time I'm having a problem while running multiple jquery functions. If I remove any one of the jQuery functions (total code feature) then other one works fine, but I need both of these.

http://www.kidsartvalley.com/kidsartvalley/account-setting-gallery2.html

See the address above for an example of what I'm talking about. Kindly don't pay attention to the design of the page. That's a different issue, but will be resolved.

The one jQuery function is "album viewer" and the other one is "POST YOUR PHOTOS" at the right corner of page above the heading of gallery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the scripts, it's because you're loading JQuery multiple times:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kidsartvalley.com/shinetime/shinetime/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Swap those with this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. jQuery safeguards its namespace by reassigning/renaming preexisting occurrences of the `jQuery` and `$` methods/objects. The last declaration would be king.

Comment: Never mind my above comment - I took a second look at the `jQuery` source and the renaming occur within the closure's scope and not in the `document` scope. Ma' bad. :)

Comment: look here we've two options .. "Post your photos" dropdown menu doesn't work at all..

Comment: though gallery viewer working good but i want to make working of "Post your photos" dropdown fine.. plz help guys

Comment: Just make sure you're loading JQuery once above all else, otherwise you'll be overwriting code which depends on the first load: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/sXN36/

Comment: Close up this question and start a new question with your new issue after you have fixed your code to use the single JQuery instance. Shouldn't be debugging new issues in a comment thread.

Comment: once again.. i'm so glad .. and would like to thank stackoverflow and you.. love your seniors..

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give us any information about what jQuery code in your page is causing a problem, all anyone here can do is look at the errors in your page and tell you to fix them.  If you want more specific advice, then be more specific about what jQuery code you want help with.

In your page, I see an error on this line and I think it's because there's no object with an id of "lofslidecontent45" on the page or be3cause that object doesn't have a method "lofJSidernews":

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){    
        jQuery('#lofslidecontent45').lofJSidernews( { interval:6000,
                                                easing:'easeInOutQuad',
                                                duration:1200,
                                                auto:true } );                      
    });
```